# Levelling Data Exception on Ender 3 V2 Neo

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, firmware, creality, automatic-bed-leveling

I was having problems where the nozzle was shaking on my Ender 3 V2 neo, so I tightened the screws holding to where the nozzle was mounted (which were quite loose), but then when I tried to print something, I got the error: "Leveling data exception, please leveling it manually first before auto-leveling." I leveled it manually, and I was still getting the error. I noticed that the firmware was outdated, so I tried updating that thinking it might fix the problem, but in trying to upgrade to V4.2.2 from V1.1.5 I only got to V1.1.6.